# CMake not building .dll file but creating .dir instead

Tags: c++, dll, cmake, clion

I have been trying to use CMake with the Clion IDE to create a DLL file. When running to cmake I instead end up with a folder that looks like this. I am running this on Windows, but would prefer not to use Visual Studio if possible which could actually create QuadCopter.dll which I could then use the functions within in other contexts.

[image: This is the folder it is creating]

My Cmake file is shown below I have ran this with the SHARED and STATIC modifiers and it doesnt seem to make a difference. Other people online say static should do what I want but it doesnt seem to. I actually want a .dll file I can then use elsewhere and not this folder that is being made. If you know how to help could you include your whole solution as I am not familiar with CMake so what may be obvious to you will be very helpful for me. From what I have read this shouldnt be as difficult as I am finding it.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(QuadCopter)
#add_library(QuadCopter SHARED main.h main.cpp)
add_library(QuadCopter STATIC main.h main.cpp)
```

Comment: have you built the project after running cmake? It looks like you haven't as there are no built object files in your screenshot. You definitely need to use `SHARED` not `STATIC` if you want to build a dll

Comment: You need `SHARED` for dlls (or `MODULE`, if the lib is loaded dynamically, but not linked). The output directory looks a lot like the result of the configure step of cmake. Are there different ways to trigger configuration and build in clion? If so have you triggered the latter after the former?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the solution was simple enough, the CMake was creating a directory but I didnt know that I actually had to run a second step to build the dll. That you fabian for the comment.